# missing new files from my project in Visual Sourcesafe 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project that I keep in VSS 2005. I recently added some new code (working in C#) which includes new files with some new classes, a file with some enum types, and a file with several static Strings. I have checked back in recursively my project a couple of times and still the files are not in VSS. With the project still checked in, I open the project in Visual Studio and they all show locked (cannot edit) but these new files (which I think is what should happen if the files are not part of it in VSS). Any ideas what is going on? How can I make my new files part of my project in VSS?
Thanks!

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't work in VSS anymore. It's quite vulnerable, easy to corrupt... My personal preference is TFS, for developers it works similarly to VSS but it's very stable and reliable.

Comment: "Visual SourceSafe actually works for Chuck Norris"

Comment: Yeah, I know. Not my choice though... company policy. So, not much I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, drag and drop the new file in the VSS folder where it should go.

Comment: It's an option to drag and drop the new files in the VSS folder. However, I'm afraid when you check out the project in VS next time, the newly added files will not be checked out along with the others. You can try to confirm this.

In addition, as Roy suggested, it is recommended to use another version control tool to replace VSS.